# Can't add Procfile to Git Repo

Tags: git

I made changes in my Procfile file for my Django website. The first time, I didn't capitalize `Procfile` so I removed the old file using `git rm procfile -f` and then typed `git add Procfile` but I got this error message:

```
fatal: pathspec 'Procfile' did not match any files
```

How can I add Procfile back to my project? I realize this was a stupid error on my part but I want to learn how to fix it and just move on with this project already. Thank you.

Comment: Could you please give us the results of `git status` and `ls` at the root of your repository?

Comment: After typing `git status`, I committed `Procfile` to the master branch and pushed the changes. But when I typed `git ls-files`, Procfile isn't in the list. Is it supposed to be there or did I make another error?

Comment: I'm guessing that this could be caused by `Procfile` being in your `.gitignore`, or by having the `Procfile` deleted locally.

Comment: I didn't delete my Procfile, but how would I get said file out of `.gitignore`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I misinterpreted your question. Are you on a Mac?

Comment: I'm on a Ubuntu virtual machine on a Mac.

Comment: I'm not sure if this fully solves your problem, so I'm going to hold off on posting this as an answer, but please try this: `git checkout HEAD Procfile`.

Answer (score 0):

You said you are using Ubuntu, so I am assuming that your filesystem is case sensitive.

### How to restore the Procfile and rename it

```
git checkout HEAD Procfile # undo deleting the Procfile
git mv Procfile procfile # rename the file to lowercase and stage it
git commit # commit your changes
```

### Explanation

`git rm procfile -f` removes the `procfile` from your filesystem and stages its deletion (though the change is not committed). `git add Procfile` attempts to add a file named `Procfile` to your staging area, but it does not seem to exist.